# Livewire v3 resetPage with multiple paginators dont work in search

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-pagination

I have a livewire LawyerComponent component where I have 2 searches on different models. In the view I cannot get the table corresponding to the search to return to page 1 when displaying the results of said search. It works for me in other components when I have only one search. I have not been able to find in the documentation how to tell $this->resetPage() the respective search. Here are my codes:

AbogadosComponent

```
    public function updatingSearch(): void
    {
        $this->gotoPage(1);
    }

    public function updatingSearchJuzgados(): void
    {
        $this->gotoPage(1);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        if($this->rolExiste()){
            $users = User::role($this->rol)
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('apellido', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('fono', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                        ->orWhereHas('abogado', function ($subquery) {
                            // Búsqueda por el campo 'rut' en la relación de 1 a 1
                            $subquery->where('rut', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                                ->orWhere('obs', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%');
                        })
                        ->orWhereHas('juzgados', function ($subquery) {
                            // Búsqueda por el campo 'name' en la relación de n a m con juzgados
                            $subquery->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%');
                        })
                        ->orWhereHas('competencias', function ($subquery) {
                            // Búsqueda por el campo 'name' en la relación de n a m con competencias
                            $subquery->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%');
                        });
                })
                ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                ->paginate($this->numberRows);
        }
        else{
            $users = $this->getEmptyPaginatedCollection();
        }
        
        return $users;
    }


    #[Computed()]
    public function juzgados()
    {
        return Juzgado::where('name','like','%'.$this->searchJuzgados.'%')
                    ->where('is_active', true)
                    ->whereDoesntHave('abogados', function (Builder $query) {
                                $query->where('user_id', $this->userId);
                            })
                    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                    ->paginate($this->numberRowsJuzgado, pageName: 'juzgadosPage');
                    
    }
```

The view:

```
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row justify-content-between">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <span class="pt-2">Mostrar&nbsp;</span>
                            <select wire:model.live='numberRows' id="numberRows" class="form-select" style="width: 70px;">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="col-6 ml-auto"> <!-- Aplicar ml-auto para alinear a la derecha -->
                                <input wire:model.live='search' name="search" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>        
                    <div class="table-responsive"> <!-- Agregar esta clase para hacer que la tabla sea responsiva -->
                        <table class="table mt-2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Fono</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Rut</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">Acciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @forelse($this->users as $user)
                                    <tr wire:key="{{ $user->id }}">
                                        <th scope="row">{{ $user->id }}</th>
                                        <td>{{ $user->fullName() }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $user->fono }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @if($user->abogado)
                                                {{-- {{ ($user->abogado)? $user->abogado->rut: 'No tiene' }}--}}
                                                 {{ $user->abogado->rut }}
                                            @else
                                                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-secondary">No tiene</span>
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @if($user->is_active)
                                                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Activo</span>
                                            @else 
                                                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-secondary">Inactivo</span>
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm d-inline" wire:click="competenciasUser({{ $user }})" title="Competencias"><i class="fas fa-light fa-layer-group"></i></button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm d-inline" wire:click="juzgadosUser({{ $user }})" title="Juzgados"><i class="fas fa-light fa-gavel"></i></button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm d-inline" wire:click="editUser({{ $user }})" title="Editar"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm d-inline" wire:click="deleteUser({{ $user }})" title="Eliminar"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @empty
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">No se encontraron abogados</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforelse
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pagination pagination-sm text-secondary justify-content-end">
                        {{ $this->users->links('vendor.livewire.bootstrap',['onPageChange' => 'updatingSearch']) }}
                    </div>
                </div>



    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <select wire:model.live='numberRowsJuzgado' id="numberRowsJuzgado" class="form-select" style="width: 70px;">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                </select>
                <div class="col-10 ml-auto"> <!-- Aplicar ml-auto para alinear a la derecha -->
                    <input wire:model.live='searchJuzgados' name="searchJuzgados" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="table-responsive"> <!-- Agregar esta clase para hacer que la tabla sea responsiva -->
            <table class="table mt-2">
                <tbody>
                    @forelse($this->juzgados as $juzgado)
                        <tr wire:key="{{ $juzgado->id }}">
                            <td>{{ $juzgado->name }}</td>
                            <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm d-inline" wire:click="addJuzgadosUser( {{ $userId }}, {{ $juzgado->id }} )" title="Asignar"><i class="bi bi-plus"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @empty
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">No se encontraron juzgados</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforelse
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination pagination-sm text-secondary justify-content-end">
           {{ $this->juzgados->links('vendor.livewire.bootstrap',['onPageChange' => 'updatingSearchJuzgados']) }}
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*resetPage()* has a *$pageName* parameter which by default is *'page'*

For the second paginator where you set *'juzgadosPage'* as the page variable name, you need to do this:

```php
$thids->resetPage('juzgadosPage');
```

The same thing for *gotoPage()*:

```php
$thids->gotoPage(1, 'juzgadosPage');
```